# Webpage to choose and upload file for Android 4.4.2 stock browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, android-4.4-kitkat

I have faced with Android 4.4.2 stock browser `<input type="file">` issue in my ASP.Net MVC web application. Found solution here [HTML file input in android webview (android 4.4, kitkat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882331/html-file-input-in-android-webview-android-4-4-kitkat) but this is acceptable only for Android WebView app.

Also found that file could be uploaded using ajax request [File Upload without Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form), but can't figure out how to get `pictureInput.files[0]` object in this case without `<input type="file">` tag.

Is there any way to get this work or workaround this Android 4.4.2 stock browser issue for Webpage?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244001/file-upload-not-working-in-android-4-4-2

Comment: mine created 2014-11-19, upper was created 2014-12-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to get this working on Android 4.4.2.

All you can do is intercept the `onclick` or `onchange` events on the `<input type="file">` because these are still fired.