# Android 4.4.2 html file upload working or not ? Need a solution not a workaround

Tags: javascript, android, file-upload, webview

I'am implementing an android application with a webview that opens an html page containing an html input of "file" type.
I implemented the openFileChooser and onShowFileChooser so that all android version from 2.2 to 6.0 are working as expected : the expected behavior is to open the camera after the click on the input field.

The problem is specifically with Android 4.4.2 where the system is not calling the fileChooser method

I searched on Stackoverflow and i found various *solutions* ( workarounds let me say ) and threads discussing this problem and suggesting the use of javascript interface or plugins ...

Many people say that there is no way to get fileupload work on 4.4.2

[This link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027649/webpage-to-choose-and-upload-file-for-android-4-4-2-stock-browser)

[Issue 62220 on Android project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220)

Ok, maybe i missed something ! but then why are the browsers ( chrome, native browser on samsung, firefox, opera, uc browser ) ok with fileupload on 4.4.2
Firefox is not using the WebView but the GeckoView maybe it's an answer, chrome is Google's browser ( using system dedicated access or something like that ? ) samsung internet browser ( the constructor's browser using system dedicated access or something like that ? ) but what for Opera and UC Browser

So wether i'am missing something and it's impossible to get the webview work on 4.4.2 with fileuploads, wether there is a solution somewhere and those who says that there's no way to do that are wrong.

Some help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my own question : Either these apps embed chromium code and use it's implementation of WebView instead of the System based implementation ( containing this bug in the case of 4.4.2 and different between each Android version ) or they have their own web engine to rely on and don't rely on webview