# Upload image without using form or "enctype"

Tags: javascript, php

This is my html

```
<div style = "margin-left: 10px"> 
<img id = "prev"src="defaultimg.jpg" alt="Default Profile Pic" width="220" height =  "220">
<input style="margin-top:10px;" value = "xxxx" id = "newphoto" type="file" name = "myimg">
```

and heres my php.

```
    $photox = $_POST['photo'];
    $target = '/images/';
    $photo = $target . basename($_FILES['myimg']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'], $photo);
```

an error occur that undefined variable "mying". . Please help

Comment: that is not possible you need both `form` as well as `entype` tag

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form

Comment: When i add form and enctype THe same error occur.

Comment: @user3099298, I use javascript .

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS **formdata** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

and perform AJAX