# Proper way to use connect-multiparty with express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser, busboy

I am trying to upload files to my server and extract them from the post request using the `connect-multiparty` middleware.  However, when I receive the request on the server, the `req.files` and `req.body` objects are empty (not null, but `node-inspector` shows that they are `Object`s with nothing in them.

Here is the code that I'm working with:

server.js:

```
var express = require( "express" );
var app = express();
var server = require( "http" ).Server( app );
var fs = require( "fs" );
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );
app.use( multipart() );

app.post( "/httpUpload", function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Received post request" );
}
```

index.html:

```
<form action="/httpUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="uploadFileInput">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I've gotten similar results trying to use `multer`, `connect-busboy`, and `body-parser`.  I would have loved if this solution worked for me, but it didn't: http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

So ... the only common theme in all of my failed attempts is me. ;o)  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... this isn't quite an answer to my question, but when I changed my code to remove the form and send the post request via jQuery's `ajax` method, the `req.files` object had my data in it.  (shrug)  Here was the code in my js that made it work:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "/httpUpload",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false, // important
    contentType: false, // important
    dataType : "json",
    data: formData
} );
```

This is the post that put me on the right path:
[File Upload without Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form)

Comment: This is because as per the README, you need to use the multipary Form() object to use forms: https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty#usage

Answer (score 2):

here is my way of extracting the uploaded files :

```
var express = require('express');
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty({ uploadDir: './imagesPath' });

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', multipartyMiddleware, function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, req.files);
  var file = req.files.file;
  console.log(file.name);
  console.log(file.type);
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

module.exports = router;
```

this will save you uploded files to imagesPath folder

Comment: Do we need to remove the file from the uploaded directory after processing it or saving it?

Comment: Using this, the file is uploaded before reaching the callback function.
I want to upload the file after a few checks like type/size etc. How can we achieve this?