# Upload file from angular to API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, angular-http

I'm trying to upload a file via angular.

So far I can select the file and post it from the angular end but I can't get the controller to receive the file.

this is how I post the file:

```
var f = new FormData();
f.append("file", file);

$http.post("/LoadFile", f);
```

but I can't seem to get my controller to receive the file. I've tried all the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(object file)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpRequestMessage request)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
```

If I add breakpoint to the methods the only one that gets hit is the last one.

Comment: Please See This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730489/how-to-upload-a-file-in-restangularjs-using-multipart-formdata/33751217#33751217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted.

I just needed to add the following the post method:

```
$http.post("/LoadFile", f, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            });
```