# Ajax file upload outside of form without plugins

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, upload

I've been searching for a solution to upload files using Ajax when the input field is not inside a form tag. I have already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form).

**This is my HTML**

```
<span id="user-image-up-btn">Last opp bilde</span>
<input id="user_image_upload" type="file" />
```

This is my code, and I get the return `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$("#user_image_upload").files')` or when I use alternative number 2, I get `Object, object`.

**This is my jQuery**

```
// IMAGE UPLOAD
$("#user_image_upload").change(function() {
    var fileform = new FormData();
    fileform.append('pictureFile', $("#user_image_upload").files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/userimageupload',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data: fileform,
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            $("#user-image-up-btn").html('Laster opp...');
            console.log(fileform);
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#user-image-up-btn").html('Last opp bilde');
            console.log(fileform);
        },
        error: function(exception){
            alert('error:'+exception);
            console.log(fileform);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
By using the answer from Adeneo I managed to upload the files. However, I still get `error:[object Object]`, which causes the rest of the form to fail. How come?

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery object has no `files` property, that would be the underlying DOM node

```
$("#user_image_upload").on('change', function() {
    var fileform = new FormData();
    fileform.append('pictureFile', this.files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/userimageupload',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data: fileform,
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            $("#user-image-up-btn").html('Laster opp...');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#user-image-up-btn").html('Last opp bilde');
        },
        error: function(exception){
            alert('error:'+exception);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, does `this` use the ID element in the function? :)

Comment: Yes, `this` inside an event handler is always the element that was targeted, without the jQuery wrapping.

Comment: The upload works but for some reason I get the following: `error:[object Object]`

Comment: If you stop using alerts to debug, and do `console.log('error', exception);` you can see what actually went wrong in the console, I suspect a parse error, i.e. that you didn't return valid JSON from the server, which is what you're expecting as you've added a `dataType : 'json'` setting

Comment: If I wish to return a HTML code, what should I set the dataType as?

Comment: You'd set it to `html`, or just not set it at all