# Uploading File in AngularJS without submit button

Tags: angularjs, forms, form-data

What is the best practices in angularjs when submitting file without a submit button.
Here is my sample code.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
   <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

I already tried using onchange, very useful also but what i want is after selecting a file it will make an ajax call (without submit button).

Comment: I think this could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26711257/1281305

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel. There are some cool libraries for this purpose like [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) as the first example.

Comment: Just make a post request with form data, 5 lines of code. No need for fancy library if you just want to upload the file.

Comment: ng-file-upload is so powerfull.. Thank you so much for your help... cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used ngpload module for it.

[ngpload](https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload)

please refer the document from the link this will definitely help you a lot