# File upload from AngularJS to Spring MVC on Tomcat 8 gives this error: Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data, tomcat8

I'm trying to upload a file from AngularJS frontend to Spring MVC backend, using Tomcat 8 server.

This is my AngularJS controller function:

```
vm.add = function(photo) {
                let file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    let photoFile = e.target.result;
                    photoService.create($routeParams.lid, photo,photoFile).then(
                            function(response) {
                                $location.path('/books');
                                vm.photo = response.data;
                            })
                }
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            }
```

This is my service function, still on the AngularJS side:

```
service.create = function(bookId, photo, file) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', photo.name);
            formData.append('file', file);
            return $http(
                    {
                        url : BASE_URL + authService.getToken().id
                        + '/book/' + bookId + '/photo/',
                        method : 'POST',
                        data : formData,
                        headers : {
                            'Content-Type' : undefined
                        },
                        transformRequest: angular.identity
                    }).then(function(res) {
                return res;
            });
         };
```

I have this bean in my dispatcher xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
```

And this in my Spring MVC controller:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "user/{uid}/book/{lid}/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Photo create(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        @PathVariable int uid, @PathVariable int lid, 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
    return photoDAO.create(uid,lid,file);
}
```

I can send the file and save it just fine directly from the html, but for some reason sending it from AngualrJS gives me this error on the Spring side:

```
2018-09-02 17:45:00,027 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod] - Error resolving argument [4] [type=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [controllers.PhotoControllerImpl]
Method [public entities.Photo controllers.PhotoControllerImpl.create(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,int,int,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)]

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
```

Even though I do see the file in my request payload:

```
018-09-02 17:45:00,028 DEBUG [com.github.isrsal.logging.LoggingFilter] - Request: request id=4; method=POST; content type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfNOybpMz7ZO1IyZX; uri=/InfiniteLegacyREST/api/user/1/legacy/1/photo/; payload=------WebKitFormBoundaryfNOybpMz7ZO1IyZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

s
------WebKitFormBoundaryfNOybpMz7ZO1IyZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

this is a text

------WebKitFormBoundaryfNOybpMz7ZO1IyZX--
```

What is causing this? Why does uploading the file in a multipart/form-data directly submitted from the html work just fine but doing it from AngularJS doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, that @RequestParam MultipartFile you're using in your *public Photo create(...)* controller method may need to be a @RequestPart instead:

```
@RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file
```

My TightBlog app has a working example of an Spring & Angular-based file upload:  [REST controller](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/12efd9dd9f3e68aed032cc133758cabfab91ef42/src/main/java/org/tightblog/ui/restapi/MediaFileController.java#L128), [angular.js](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/12efd9dd9f3e68aed032cc133758cabfab91ef42/src/main/webapp/tb-ui/scripts/mediafileedit.js#L17) and [JSP](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/12efd9dd9f3e68aed032cc133758cabfab91ef42/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsps/editor/MediaFileEdit.jsp#L170).

Comment: I changed it to `@RequestPart` and I still see the same error.

The interesting thing as I mentioned earlier is that when I submit the file directly from the html, it works and the request logger shows that the payload contains the `Content-Type` for the file. When I send via AngularJS and $http, I see the error and there is no `Content-Type` added for the file in the payload.

Comment: Unsure, but I think you're supposed to send the file via the form, i.e., no bug here.  If someone accidentally chooses the wrong file from a choose file popup window, they want to be able to undo their action, not have a private file accidentally sent to your server as a result.

Comment: Yes, I do have a form, and when I submit it, the submit button, instead of submitting directly to the server, calls an AngularJS method that will do the submission.

<button ng-click="vm.add(photo)" type="submit">Add Photo</button>

Comment: What you want here is a file upload without an HTML form submit (the fact that you're activating your Angular upon hitting the submit button isn't really a form submit of course), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332886/uploading-file-in-angularjs-without-submit-button) topic may have some helpful links for you in the answers.