# How do I upload a file with the JS fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

I can have the user select the file (or even multiple) with the file input:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Select file to upload</label>
    <input type="file">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Convert</button>
</form>
```

And I can catch the `submit` event using `<fill in your event handler here>`. But once I do, how do I send the file using `fetch`?

```
fetch('/files', {
  method: 'post',
  // what goes here? What is the "body" for this? content-type header?
}).then(/* whatever */);
```

Comment: official document works for me after trying some answers failed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file , something can confirm: 1. need wrap file in FromData; 2. doesn't need to declare `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` in request header

Answer (score 218, accepted):

This is a basic example with comments. The `upload` function is what you are looking for:

```
// Select your input type file and store it in a variable
const input = document.getElementById('fileinput');

// This will upload the file after having read it
const upload = (file) => {
  fetch('http://www.example.net', { // Your POST endpoint
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      // Content-Type may need to be completely **omitted**
      // or you may need something
      "Content-Type": "You will perhaps need to define a content-type here"
    },
    body: file // This is your file object
  }).then(
    response => response.json() // if the response is a JSON object
  ).then(
    success => console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
  ).catch(
    error => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
  );
};

// Event handler executed when a file is selected
const onSelectFile = () => upload(input.files[0]);

// Add a listener on your input
// It will be triggered when a file will be selected
input.addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false);
```

Comment: Why does this example include Content-Type headers but another answer says to omit them when sending files with Fetch API? Which one is it?

Comment: Do NOT set Content-Type. I spent a lot of time trying to make it work and then found this article saying to not set it. And it works! https://muffinman.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/

Comment: how would you read this file from let's say Express backend. As the file is not sent as form data. It is instead sent as just the file object. Does express-fileupload or multer parse such payloads?

Comment: is fileinput the id of the button where you click to upload?

Comment: @sakib11 My node-express server was able to receive this (with the help of bodyParser.raw()) only with the `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Just in case if someone needs to download file from one place and upload it to another: `const fileFetch = await fetch(fileDownloadUrl); const fileBlob = await fileFetch.blob(); upload(fileBlob)`

Comment: Anyone else only getting an empty object on the server side?

Answer (score 378):

I've done it like this:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')

fetch('/avatars', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the file contents in a `FormData` object if all you're uploading is the file (which is what the original question wants).  `fetch` will accept `input.files[0]` above as its `body` parameter.

Comment: If you have a PHP backend handling the file upload you will want to wrap the file in a FormData so that the $_FILES array is properly populated.

Comment: I also noticed that Google Chrome would not show the file in the request payload without the FormData part for some reason. Seems like a bug in Google Chrome's Network panel.

Comment: This should really be the correct answer. The other way works also but is more convoluted

Comment: what do you mean by /avatars? Are you referring to some backend API endpoint?

Comment: how would you read this file from let's say Express backend. As the file is not sent as form data. It is instead sent as just the file object. Does express-fileupload or multer parse such payloads?

Comment: Just remember that you'll need a multi-part body parser to parse the formdata. A good module for this is "formidable": https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable#readme

Comment: @sakib11 The file is sent within the form data, so you'll need a parser that parses multi-part bodies. So yes, Multer would work since it parses `multipart/form-data`, which is what the form data is.

Comment: Using `FormData` when uploading from browser to S3 with presigned URLs will make the file corrupted in S3. And tbh, any backend can handle file upload without `FormData`, including PHP.

Comment: I use FastApi with `def upload_file(file: UploadFile):` and it would not work without `FormData`. So thank you for your advice!

Comment: Best answer. How to get `user` at the backend? (eg. Django or PHP)

Comment: @sakib11 if you are only sending a single file from fetch then you can use `express.raw()` method to access it. after accessing the buffer (ex: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227838/13922407)) you can use `.toString` or `.toJson`  or any buffer methods to convert the data to your requirement

Answer (score 179):

An important note for sending Files with Fetch API

One needs to omit  `content-type` header for the Fetch request. Then the browser will automatically add the `Content type` header including the Form Boundary which looks like

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundaryfgtsKTYLsT7PNUVD
```

Form boundary is the delimiter for the form data

Comment: THIS! Very important! Don't use your own content-type with fetch on multipart. I had no idea why my code does not work.

Comment: [fetch - Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39280438/86967)

Comment: This is gold! I wasted 1 hr not understanding this. Thanks for sharing this tip

Comment: This is very important info which is not captured in the [MDN Fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file).

Comment: In chrome it will default to text/plain. This won't work if you have set some custom headers of yours.

Answer (score 54):

If you want multiple files, you can use this

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
for (const file of input.files) {
  data.append('files',file,file.name)
}

fetch('/avatars', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

Comment: Note that explicitly passing `file.name` as the filename isn't necessary; per the [MDN docs on `FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), the default name for `File` objects already is the file's filename.

Answer (score 34):

To submit a single file, you can simply use the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object from the `input`'s `.files` array directly as the value of `body:` in your `fetch()` initializer:

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');

// Later, perhaps in a form 'submit' handler or the input's 'change' handler:
fetch('https://example.com/some_endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: myInput.files[0],
});
```

This works because `File` inherits from [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and `Blob` is one of the permissible [`BodyInit`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin) types defined in the Fetch Standard.

Comment: This is the simplest answer but how does `body: myInput.files[0]` cause to the amount of bytes held in memory at the client side ?

Comment: I would *expect* that with this solution the browser would be sensible enough to stream the file and not require it to be read into memory, @bhantol, but I haven't gone out of my way to find out (either empirically or by delving into the spec). If you wanted to confirm, you could try (in each of the major browsers) using this approach to upload a 50GB file or something, and see whether your browser tries to use too much memory and gets killed.

Comment: Did not work for me. `express-fileupload` failed to parse the request stream. But `FormData` works like a charm.

Comment: @attacomsian At a glance, it looks to me like `express-fileupload` is a serverside library for handling `multipart/form-data` requests that contain files, so yeah, it's not compatible with this approach (which just directly sends the file as the request body).

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer here is a bit dated. As of April 2020, a recommended approach seen on the MDN website suggests using `FormData` and also does not ask to set the content type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

I'm quoting the code snippet for convenience:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const fileField = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

formData.append('username', 'abc123');
formData.append('avatar', fileField.files[0]);

fetch('https://example.com/profile/avatar', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Using `FormData` will only work if the server is expecting form data. If the server wants a raw file as the body of the POST the accepted answer is correct.

Comment: @Clyde what do you mean? I thought it was the client that decides what type of content to send to the server?

Comment: Yes, but the client and server have to agree on what content can be sent and how it is encoded. It is certainly possible to write server code to accept either a raw POST body or FormData (the headers will say what encoding has been used by the client) but often the server will be expecting a specific encoding so you have to send content that matches that.

Answer (score 11):

It would be nice to add php endpoint example.
So that is js:

```
const uploadinput = document.querySelector('#uploadinputid');
const uploadBtn = document.querySelector('#uploadBtnid');
uploadBtn.addEventListener('click',uploadFile);

async function uploadFile(){
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('nameusedinFormData',uploadinput.files[0]);    
    try{
        const response = await fetch('server.php',{
            method:'POST',
            body:formData
        } );
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);

    }
}
```

That is php:

```
$file = $_FILES['nameusedinFormData'];
$temp = $file['tmp_name'];
$target_file = './targetfilename.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Comment: The question makes no assumption as to the backend techology used to upload the file.

Comment: Yet somehow it’s still helpful to others learning and reading

Answer (score 5):

Jumping off from Alex Montoya's approach for multiple file input elements

```
const inputFiles = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');
const formData = new FormData();

for (const file of inputFiles) {
    formData.append(file.name, file.files[0]);
}

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData })
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem for me was that I was using a response.blob() to populate the form data. Apparently you can't do that at least with react native so I ended up using

```
data.append('fileData', {
  uri : pickerResponse.uri,
  type: pickerResponse.type,
  name: pickerResponse.fileName
 });
```

Fetch seems to recognize that format and send the file where the uri is pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

html:

```js
const upload = (file) => {
    console.log(file);

    

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/files/uploadFile', { 
    method: 'POST',
    // headers: {
    //   //"Content-Disposition": "attachment; name='file'; filename='xml2.txt'",
    //   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=BbC04y " //"multipart/mixed;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p" //  ή // multipart/form-data 
    // },
    body: file // This is your file object
  }).then(
    response => response.json() // if the response is a JSON object
  ).then(
    success => console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
  ).catch(
    error => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
  );

  //cvForm.submit();
};

const onSelectFile = () => upload(uploadCvInput.files[0]);

uploadCvInput.addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false);
```

```html
<form id="cv_form" style="display: none;"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="uploadCV" type="file" name="file"/>
          <button type="submit" id="upload_btn">upload</button>
</form>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" id="upload">UPLOAD CV</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" id="download">DOWNLOAD CV</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

##### How to upload a single file on select using HTML5 `fetch`

```html
<label role="button">
  Upload a picture
  <input accept="image/*" type="file" hidden />
</label>
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector(`input[type="file"]`);

function upload() {
  fetch(uploadURL, { method: "PUT", body: input.files[0] });
}

input.addEventListener("change", upload);
```