# app.post doesn't receive any response when fetch was initiated

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want to send a file to the node server which requires something from the front end. I looked around to see how I could use my app.post("",req) to retrieve confirmation of a website. However I came across a problem.

Here is the sample code:

```js
fetch(slink, {method: "POST", headers:{
 "Content-type":"application/json"
}, body: {request: "Site Request"}}).then((resp)=>{
 return resp.json();
```

Thats the front end, now the back end (server side)...

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/resources",(req, resp)=>{
 console.log(req.body)
 resp.json(jsnfile) // this part works however
})
```

When these two are run together, the javascript on the front end isn't received on the back end, which returns an empty dictionary {}. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't seem like you're sending a file whith your `fetch()` request. Try using this:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

# If you gonna take a file from the input
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', input.files[0]);

# Asuming 'slink' is a valid url
fetch(slink, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
});
```

Possible duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-html5-js-fetch-api).

### EDIT

If you want to send a JSON object you just replace this line `data.append('file', input.files[0]);` to something like this `data.append( "json", JSON.stringify(data));` and send it like previously.

Comment: What if you don't want to give the server a form file but instead just a dictionary, is that still possible?

Comment: @GlennParale I updated my answer, hope it will help you!