# How to send multiple POST requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a html form that contains some fields to include user credentials and a file input, something like this:

```
<form action="">
    username: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"> <br/>
    secret key: <input type="password" name="key" id="key"> <br/>

    <input type="file" name="actual_upload" id="actual_upload">
</form>
```

I want to upload the file to server `S2` only after the user credentials has been verified, and a unique token has been generated by another server `S1` (returns the token as `JSON`).

One way I thought of doing this is posting it to `S1` and then forward the request from `S1` to `S2`. But this way I have to receive the complete request in `S1`, which unnecessarily increases `S1`'s load.

If I put the user credentials in the request header instead of the request body, is there a way to send only the headers to `S1` and then after receiving the token, use that to send the file to `S2` ? Or is there another way?

Comment: i don't think so this is related with JS alone anymore.. You should make the backend do the job instead of frontend

Comment: yeah, use AJAX - you can make the second request once the first request returns the token for you

Comment: @JaromandaX mind showing me some code examples?

Comment: no, because there's literally a billion examples on SO alone :p

Comment: You might want to look into the use of Promises.

Comment: Use a callback to make the call. Promise can also be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, you can use either AJAX or Promises. A simple implementation would be to use the `fetch` API.

Here's a sample code structure that you can use (I'm assuming you do have a `submit` button in your form):

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', uploadFile);

function uploadFile() {

    event.preventDefault();

    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let key = document.getElementById('key').value;

    let S1Url = // endpoint where token will be generated 

    fetch(S1Url, {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(function(response){
        // extract token from JSON response
        // return token
    }).then(function(token) {
        let S2Url = // endpoint where file will be uploaded

        // file that has been selected in the form
        let input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', input.files[0]);

        return fetch(S2Url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        });

    }).then(function(response){
        // do something with the response
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
    });
}
```

Checkout this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) where there are good number of examples that uses `fetch` API. Also, take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api).