# React file upload with FormData

Tags: reactjs, multipartform-data, multer

Trying to upload file using FormData. File is uploading to server successfully and appears in uploads folder, but server sends back "Bad request". On server

```
"message": "\"file\" is required"
```

Seems like multer not parsing file to body so `req.body.file` doesn't exist. Similar code in Angular works as clock. Where's the difference?

**React:**

```js
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let body = new FormData();

    let data = Array.prototype.filter.call(e.target.elements, 
      (input) => {
        if (input.nodeName === 'BUTTON') return false;
        return true;
      });
    Array.prototype.map.call(data, (input) => {
      input.id !== 'file' ? body.append( input.id, input.value )
      : body.append('file', input.files[0]);
      
    });
    fetch('http://localhost:4040/api/books/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')
     },
     body: body,
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data" className="form-add">
        <input type="file" id="file" accept=".jpg, .png" required />
        <input type="text" id="author" placeholder="author" required />
        <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" required />
        <textarea id="description" rows="10" placeholder="Description..." required ></textarea>
        <input type="number" id="rating" placeholder="Number from 1 to 5" min="1" max="5" required/>
        <select name="status" id="status">
          <option value="true">true</option>
          <option value="false">false</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

**Angular:**

```js
@ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;
  // Loading file
  addFile(): any {
    let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (fi.files && fi.files[0]) {
        return fi.files[0];
    }
    return null;
  }

  onSubmit(value: string) {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append("file",this.addFile());
    Object.keys(this.form.value).forEach(k => {
      body.append(k, this.form.value[k]);
    });
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') })
    };
    this.http.post('http://localhost:4040/api/books/create', body, httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Success!');
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: input.files[0] have file?

Comment: Yes, file is attached to formdata correctly

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. maybe this link help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082038/5765981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on server side in validation params. Now it looks like`file: Joi.any()`