# Need help on getting an image file as text using Javascript FileReader

Tags: javascript, php, image, file, filereader

I've been finding a way to insert an image to database via AJAX. 
Instead of submitting through form, I'd like to convert the image file into text (longblob), then send it to the PHP script via POST variable so I can access them via $_POST['var_name'] , then insert them normally through SQL, but **the problem is**, the Javascript FileReader couldn't return the valid image text AS IF you would normally obtain from the PHP side by using the fopen and fread funtions. I need to find a way to convert an image into text (longblob), so I can insert them into the table .

I tried using the `FileReader`, then chose `fileReader.readAsText`, but the result dosen't seems to be valid for type longblob in the database

```
// Here is in the JavaScript //

let image_file = document.getElementById("upload_image").files[0];
let vars = "image_data=";

let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onloadend = function()
{
   // I pass in callback function, so I get this.result to assign else where
    callBack(this.result);
}

fileReader.readAsText(image_file);

// Then, I concat the image text to the vars variable
vars += result;

/* By this time vars would be "image_data=#$@#$DGJ#J$@#!$#@$@$..."(some 
   converted string),but the problem is this image_data does not contain 
   the correct image string (when get from $_POST on the PHP side) . I 
   would like to know if there're any ways to get the correct image 
   string as if it's obtained by using fopen, then fread function on the 
   PHP side*/
```

Here is the correct image string from the PHP

����JFIF``��LEAD Technologies Inc. V1.01���        ���  }!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������"0��?�ۭ D��V02��7��k����"��:���Kc�j��}������2c��8�j�#���9^W���B�l��C���Ո�LFW2�'�=G��Զ3���6��?�j��[b,޿(�*�%o;�&[p:����Ƭ��lM�c* �O� �n�6��df�Y�>8�t9�rNd��(��[��݋��kxc��Ҹn۸\�Ү���;�1����^�N��%ux���.$%�Q�)�^�V.R�lI�'ʸ?....

The image file string after opened by using fopen and using fread functions. The real text that I echo out has 20000+ letters long, but on the JavaScipt FileReader, it gives me this..

����JFIF``��LEAD Technologies Inc. V1.01���        ���  }!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %

Yes, that's it! As you can see both results are pretty much the same. I'd love to know why I didn't get the same text to the PHP script from the JavaScript FileReader. Anyone know how to solve this? or maybe please give some suggestions on sending files via AJAX. Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you want to do this?? It would be much easier to just send the file via AJAX/FormData (or by regular form submission). PHP is perfectly capable of receiving an uploaded file. If you then need to get the content in order to use it in your SQL, you can do that in PHP using the techniques you already know about. I can't help but feel you're overcomplicating this simple task.

Comment: Are there any ways to convert image into text and send them through post or get variables to the server side script?

Comment: Reading as text would url-escape some characters try `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` instead

Comment: @piyapank maybe there are, but again... why?? Keep your code simple. Let JavaScript upload the file. Let PHP process it and insert the data into the database. Chances are, converting it to a string in JS will also make your upload slightly bigger, which is less efficient, as is using processing time in the browser to do something unnecessary. It doesn't make sense to do this, and you haven't explained any reason why you need to. I strongly urge you to spend your time and energy in something more useful.

Comment: P.S. You asked "maybe please give some suggestions on sending files via AJAX"...you can google it in 20 seconds, just search for "ajax file upload" or similar. Here's one example using jQuery: https://artisansweb.net/ajax-file-upload-php-jquery/. Here's another using fetch(): https://time2hack.com/2018/08/upload-files-to-php-backend-using-fetch-formdata/ . And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api. You can find dozens, if not hundreds, of tutorials and examples like this very easily.