# Redux Toolkit + RTK + Multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, multer, redux-toolkit

How upload an image with RTK and Multer ?

**JSX file**

```
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
 
      const payload = new FormData();
      payload.append("imagegif", image);
      payload.append("title", formData.titre);

      addPost(payload);
};
```

**createapi**

```
addPost: build.mutation<"testid", FormData>({
  query: (body) => ({
    url: `posts`,
    method: 'POST',
    body,
  }),
  invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }],
}),
```

**Multer file**

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES = {
  "image/jpg": "jpg",
  "image/jpeg": "jpg",
  "image/png": "png",
  "image/gif": "gif"
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: '../images/',
  filename: "test.gif"
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single("imagegif");
```

**routes**

```
router.post("/", auth,multer,  posts.createPost);
```

Folder "images is created but no file inside it.

I don't find sample with RTK and file upload.

Comment: There is nothing really special regarding RTK and file uploads - fetchBaseQuery is just a wrapper around fetch, so you pretty much do it as you would do it using fetch. There are a few examples for that in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api

Answer (score 0):

`payload.append("title", formData.titre);`

Maybe not related but, shouldn't be formData.title at least?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "titre" is "title", at least in e.g. French.