# How upload photo using fetch?

Tags: javascript, post, file-upload, fetch-api, form-data

I try to upload photo from my PC using fetch, but code below doesn't work. Url is right. What is the problem?

```
 static async sendPostFormDataRequest(url) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("nameField", "C://sample.jpeg");
    fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",           
        body: formData
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to use a `file` input. JavaScript in browser has no direct access to file system.

Comment: I'm an absolute beginner in javascript. Could you clarify what it is about with work example?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api If the point is automation you should probably use another tool like nodejs