# How to get file from an action method which is downloading

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here is my sample code which I got from a website which converts xls to xlsx. It downloads the file immediately after converting it to xlsx, so I want to use that file further as blob. so is there any way to use that file which I will receive from action method using JavaScript?
Thank you!

HTML Code :

```
<form action="https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/xls/to/xlsx?Secret=...&download=attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="File" /> 
   <input type="hidden" name="FileName" value="anyName" /> 
   <input type="submit" value="Convert file"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function convert(input){
    let obj = {
        File : input,
        FileName : 'Test'
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/xls/to/xlsx?Secret=...&StoreFile=true',
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'
        },    
        body: JSON.stringify(obj),
        success : function(res){
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    })
   }
```

Comment: do it with nodejs and its APIs https://www.convertapi.com/doc/node-library

Comment: but I can't use nodejs for some reasons.

Comment: @GrafiCode he is trying to do this client side, not server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to upload same way as you mentioned @dqhendricks but didn't worked for me.
when I tried with FormData it worked for me. It would be awesome if we could do it with just JS.

HTML :

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
            <input type="file" name="File" />
            <input type="hidden" name="FileName" value="newFile" />
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Convert file"/>
   </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
        var d = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/xls/to/xlsx?Secret=[Secret]&StoreFile=true',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            data: d,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you would use javascript's `fetch()` to upload the file to the conversion endpoint instead of using a form, then you would get the file download as a response, which you can do with what you like.

this question may help you figure out how to upload a file, but you will have to understand a bit of javascript:

[How do I upload a file with the JS fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api)

Comment: Edited question and added JS code too. 
 
I have tried fetch and ajax method too but failed to get any response from API. I'm getting this error : `{"Code":4000,"Message":"Parameter validation error.","InvalidParameters":{"File":["File size must be greater than 0 bytes.","The File field is required."]}}` please suggest

Comment: As you can see, I'm passing the file parameter as well.

Comment: @Umair it sounds like you are not uploading the file correctly. As I've said, check out the link I posted. It shows how to successfully upload a file from a file input.