# How do I run JS code when a user uploads files?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the message `You uploaded a file!` to pop up after I select a file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#uploadme").click(function() {
                    alert("You uploaded a file!")
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="uploadme"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: Listen for `input` event on the `input` element

Comment: but consider also that it will be misleading because you didn't actually upload a file yet until the form will be sumitted (or if you have an ajax action in background using that input[type=file] as source). What I'm trying to say it's that if you wish to have such a message to be real you are looking for the whole logic to upload a file using an ajax request

Comment: Can you point me to an example?

Comment: Try to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826943/1221208 but consider that the notification you are aiming at will be a further step to chain at the end when the fetch will return success

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using a listener.

```
<input type="file" id="uploadme">
<script>
  const fileSelector = document.getElementById('uploadme');
  fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    alert('You uploaded a file!')
  });
</script>
```