Fetch api fails to send the image to the server and returns a 404 error
I'm creating a function that sends an image to a server using JavaScript and Spring Boot.
However, when using the fetch API in JavaScript code to send an image file to the server, the server cannot be accessed and a 404 error occurs.
add-page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
        function submitImage() {
        const name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
            const image = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];

        const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('image', image);
            formData.append('name', name);

        fetch('/add', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error', error);
        });


    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="mt-5">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control mt-2">
        <input name="name" class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="enter" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" onclick="submitImage()">
            submit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

ImageController
@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String getAddPage() {
        return "add-page";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @RequestParam("name") String name){
        System.out.println(image);
        System.out.println(name);

        return "add-page";
    }
}

If I send a String type in formData, it arrives at the controller just fine, but if I send it including a File, it does not arrive at the controller and a 404 not found error occurs.
Can anyone tell me how to send an image file in formData using the fetch function?
I tried changing Content-Type to multipart/form-data, but it didn't work.
When I use Post Man to send the image, it arrives at the controller, but when I use the fetch function, it doesn't enter the controller.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api

You can keep the content type multipart/form-data values in your request.
Try to append your file in formData object like this formData.append('image', image, name); and remove the next line where you append name separately.

I confirmed that it's the same no matter how I edited it.
However, I found an additional problem.
It works without any problem in Edge browser and causes 404 not found issue in Chrome browser.
I don't know why this result occurred.
