# post a file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, post

I need to read a local file and post it to the server, we do not need to choose the file. The path of the file is given.

uploading a file when user manually selects works but in the above scenario we need to read an existing file and post it.

Comment: Well can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form

Answer (score -2):

I generally just require the file and upload it.

```
var file = require('path');
```

Comment: This won't work. Javascript in a browser does not have arbitrary access to the local files system. See post linked to in my previous comment for why.

Comment: Oh okay sorry then, I use javascript with react and include files in this way. So different context