# Send file without form, write file in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to transfer a file without form in a variable and without contentType: false, processData: false in ajax parameters ?

```
$(div).find('input, textarea').each(function(index, element) {
  //...
    var fileArr = []
    if (type === 'file' && element.files.length) {
       var file = $(element)[0].files[0];

         var fileData = new FormData();

         fileData.append('file', file);

         fileArr.push(fileData);
    }
    //...
}

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/sendData",
                success: function (data) {},
                error: function (error) {},
                async: true,
                data: {
                   id: 34,
                   val: 34,
                   files: fileArr
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,  //<-- without
                processData: false, //<-- without
                timeout: 10000
            });
```

> Illegal invocation

Comment: You can omit `contentType` and `processData` but you need to check about form.

Comment: you can convert it to base64 and send it.

Comment: *without form in a variable* what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Kaiido To in the cyсl when I try to check the inputs of the fillet type is a file and if there is something to assign as it is in a variable and then transfer it to ajax.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get anything... I'm kind of tired though.

Comment: Sorry, update questions for clarity. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Read the file as base64 string, send with ajax post request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449/465560

Comment: @Priya Thank's. With a large file size, will not slow load?

Comment: It depends on end users system computing power and updated browser. Yeah it will slow down if its in GB's.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('pictureFile', pictureInput.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false, // important
  contentType: false, // important
  dataType : 'json',
  data: myFormData
});
```

> source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690647/7641442

---

Anyway, as that answer says, you can avoid using an existing form by initializating a FormData() but it is needed to transfer files using ajax ^^

---

If you want to try a different approach you can try to convert the file to a string and pass it

Comment: *it is needed to transfer files using ajax*  only true through POST requests, you can send files through PUT without a FormData.

Comment: He's doing a post request

Comment: I didn't said he wasn't.

Comment: Thank's. But without processData: false, contentType: false. Update questions

Comment: Andrew, you need it, the only one possible workaround is to convert your file as a really long string