# How can I send a binary data (blob) using fetch and FormData?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The following code works as expected. Open the page "https://wiki.epfl.ch/" on Google Chrome, and execute this code on the Developer console. Note: the page "https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php" does not exists and so it fails to load, but that's not the issue.

```
response = await fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/lapa-studio/documents/DTS/laser%20tutorial.pdf");
response.text().then(function(content) { 
  formData = new FormData();
  console.log(content.length);
  console.log(content);
  formData.append("content", content);

  fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php", {method: 'POST', body: formData});
})
```

It logs:

```
content.length: 57234
content: %PDF-1.3
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x��K��F�����;¢�
...
```

Go to the Developer Network tab, choose the 'test.php' page, navigate to "Requested payload:" and you can see this content:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryOJOOGb7N43BxCRlv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"

%PDF-1.3
%���������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
...
------WebKitFormBoundaryOJOOGb7N43BxCRlv
```

The issue is that the request file is a binary file (PDF), and the text gets "mangled". It reports a size of 57234 bytes, when the actual file size (as fetched with a `wget` command) is 60248 bytes.

The question is: How to get and send the binary data, without being modified?

---

I tried replacing `response.text()` by `response.blob()`, as follows:

```
response = await fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/lapa-studio/documents/DTS/laser%20tutorial.pdf");
response.blob().then(function(content) { 
  console.log(content.size);
  console.log(content);
  formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("content", content);

  fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php", {method: 'POST', body: formData});
})
```

Now I get this log, with the correct file size:

```
content.size:  60248
content:  Blob(60248) {size: 60248, type: "application/pdf"}
```

However, going to the Developer Network tab, choose the 'test.php' page, navigate to "Requested payload:", it shows that it sends an empty payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryYoibuD14Ah2cNGAd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryYoibuD14Ah2cNGAd--
```

---

Note: The webpage I am developing is not at wiki.epfl.ch. I provide this example so that users can try it (and avoid the "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" problem). My "test.php" page is in php and `$_POST['content']` returns the content when using `response.text()`, but it returns empty when using `response.blob()`. So, even if it is the case that the Developer Network tab "Requested payload:" does not show binary data, this snipped is still not working.

Comment: _"Maybe the problem is that `response.blob()` returns a Blob object"_ How is `Body.blob()` related to the Question?

Comment: i've updated the question with more details

Comment: The second approach (with `blob()`) does actually send data. I presume that the Chrome dev tools don't show the value because it would be garbled binary data, but if you watch the request in Fiddler, you can see that data is sending. Do you have some way to check whether it's being received correctly? As far as I can tell, https://wiki.epfl.ch/test doesn't actually show any confirmation that a file was received (is it even intended for that purpose?)

Comment: The webpage I am developing is not at wiki.epfl.ch. I provide this example so that users can try (and avoid the "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" problem). My "test" page is in php and `$_POST['content']` returns empty.

Comment: @DavidPortabella I just tried out what you showed. It is in accordance with [Sending Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), but from what I see, the request is probably not being shown in the payload, but its probably getting attached. I think so for 2 reasons. (a) `formData.get("content")` returns the required blob and (b) The content length of the request header is `60434` indicating that the pdf is probably there.

Comment: See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457484, very relevant to what you're facing.

Comment: i don't think binary form chunks are shown in chrome, ever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, by converting blob to DataURL string, you can send binary data without being modified.

```
response = await fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/lapa-studio/documents/DTS/laser%20tutorial.pdf");
response.blob().then(function (content) {

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {

      formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("content", reader.result);
      fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php", { method: 'POST', body: formData });
      reader.removeEventListener("loadend");

    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(content);

 });
```

Comment: FYI using the `FileReader` API here to buffer the `Blob` is completely unnecessary. [`formData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) accepts `content` directly as a `value` rather than buffering it to `reader.result`.

Comment: To see how to use `FormData` without the `FileReader`, see the second part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48568899/1541563).

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer how to send the binary data as payload; it wraps it in a form multi-part section and sends it encoded.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to send a binary file, do not use the [`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) method, as that returns the file decoded using UTF-8, which is not what you want. Instead, use the [`.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) method, which does not attempt to decode the file, and use it directly as the `body` parameter of the second [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) since it's allowed to be a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```
const response = await fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/lapa-studio/documents/DTS/laser%20tutorial.pdf");
const content = await response.blob();
console.log(content.size);
fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php", { method: 'POST', body: content });
```

For parsing this upload format see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945912/1541563).

If you want to upload it as part of a `multipart/form-data` formatted attachment, you can still use the `FormData` API, but doing so isn't necessary to send the binary data to your PHP script. Just for completeness, here's how you'd do that instead:

```
const response = await fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/lapa-studio/documents/DTS/laser%20tutorial.pdf");
const content = await response.blob();
console.log(content.size);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("content", content);
fetch("https://wiki.epfl.ch/test.php", { method: 'POST', body: formData });
```

Comment: this was also a very good answer, though I didn't specify that I need to use mutipart/form-data to pass other values.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this code may hope it will helps you

```
 pdfcall(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = 'GET',
 xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
  xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';
  xmlhttp.onload = (e: any) => {
   console.log(xmlhttp);
if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
  let blob = new Blob([xmlhttp.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  this.pdfSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  }
};
 xmlhttp.onerror = (e: any) =>{
  console.error(e,'eerr')
    }
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```