# Sending PDF via ajax gives blank file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to send a PDF as binary string to the server (with my special case I cannot use form submit with multi part)

My issue is the uploaded file comes as blank, i.e; no content, on the server (In the below repro project please refer ~/Uploaded folder located, once clicked on the upload button).
What am I missing?

All, I need to know how to send the file from JavaScript/jQuery on to the server (I don't have access to change the server side code). Thanks in advance!

[Here is a sample repro created using ASP.NET MVC 5, (VS2017 15.7.2)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtqzJj-X1OCRibcR1XX3Alhg6c6G6w)

Comment: If you haven't already, it would be worth checking out the answers given to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690647/5957979)

Comment: Thanks Rick. I tried many of them but with no joy so far.