# Is it possible to automate the file selecting for a file input with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I sell T-shirts online, and I want to add a few hundred designs to an online marketplace. Unfortunately they don’t have any sort of bulk uploader. So I need to select a file, and fill out the description tags & title then submit.

I currently know how to automate everything in this process except the part where I need to click the file input, and select the image. If I could automate that step with a chrome extension I’d be able to start this process running and walk away.

So the big question Is if there anyway to do that with a chrome extension. Obviously this ability could have serious security implications, but I’m hoping there is some way to do it, even if I have to jump through some whitelisting hoops.

Comment: No, you can't. BTW, why not use a nodejs script instead of the browser for that purpose?

Comment: ... the only way this might be possible in a browser is by inserting a file `input` that can select multiple files at once. You can then select all your images at once and for each one, you can upload whatever you want. But you can't use a regular `form`, you'll have to use ajax or something. Here is a [starter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617996/9867451)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm embarrassed to admit maybe this is just my inexperience showing but how would nodejs help me here? In this case I'm trying to upload to threadless.com, a site I have no control over, and who doesn't have an API for design uploads as far as I can tell. So right now I have to navigate to the upload form page, then I can use a chrome extension to grab data from my database and use it to populate the form. I'm not familiar enough with nodejs to see how that could help improve my current workflow, but I'm happy to learn! Thanks.

Comment: As for your second comment, that's interesting. so perhaps I could add a multiform upload, grab all of the individual files data, and then send a post request to the form endpoint with each image one at a time? Hmmmmm, wouldn't I run into CSRF issues with that though? Assuming they have even basic CSRF protection built in...

Comment: why would there be CSRF issues? You are already doing this a lot of time (manually uploading data for each image).