# how to post image with ajax without form-data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried `var $pic1 = document.getElementById("pic").value;` give the image path: *C:fakepath/pictures/pic.jpg*

Solutions always include sending in form-data. However, I could not do it.

my images folder: **/img**

I want image upload to **'img'** folder after INSERT process.

view : https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Gxx.png

```php
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" name="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4"> 
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="pic" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" accept=".jpg,.gif,.png">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose Image</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="hidden" name="projeid" value="<?php echo $_POST['proje_id']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="add"  id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
    var name = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var action = 'insert';
    $.ajax({
        url:"data/action.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: {
            name: name,
            action: action
        },
        success:function(data) {
            load_data(projid);
        }
    });
});
```

--data/action.php--

```php
if($_POST["action"] == "insert") {
    $query = "INSERT INTO grundriss (name) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."')";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    
    echo '<p>Data Inserted...</p>';
}
```

Comment: Typically, you use a `<form>` for this. And yes, it should have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: Start with this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19447435/296555

Comment: I can't do that because others depend on it.
Isn't there a way to do it without submitting form-data?

Comment: Flagging as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19617996/296555.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File Upload without Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617996/file-upload-without-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert image to base64 and then post it with ajax.

Comment: how can i that?

Comment: You can use the HTML5 <canvas> for it:
Create a canvas, load your image into it and then use toDataURL() to get the Base64 data. Then send it via regular post variable. In php, decode base64 if u want file, otherwise simple put base64 string to database.