# How to set file object as blob/byte array on typescript interface?

Tags: angular, file

I want to have an input field with file. Put the file into an Angular object, then upload it into API.

But, when I log file, it's always empty (like `{}`). The rest API receive empty object too. Server-side result: `{"id":0,"name":"test","image":{}}`.

My object:

```js
export interface Image {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: Blob;
}
```

In my components, the HTML is `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target)" required>`, and my typescript code is:

```js
public imageEdit: Image = { id: 0, name: "something" };

public handleFileInput(file: any): void {
  let files = file.files as FileList;
  if(files.length == 1) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
    this.imageEdit.image = files.item(0); // also tried with "files[0]"
    this.http.post("my/url", this.imageEdit); // here send to server
  }
}
```

I also tried to use [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) instead of `Blob`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Vikas this send formdata, not a custom object. That's my issue, I don't know how to do without using FormData

Comment: @Elikill58 - Not sure I understand the problem with using FormData, but here's an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212708/589227

Comment: @SeanChase this doesn't solve the empty content and there is the same issue as FormData, it's not a custom object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really answer, but I change something and now it works. Now, I'm using the full body of `POST` request to send it.

On server, I'm using `context.bodyInputStream()` to get the content as stream (and put it in database as blob).

On client, with angular, I'm using `http.post("my/url", event.target.files[0])`.